# jQuery code to display only on certain rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have the following script:

```
  $("tr.member_profile_comment_row_frame").mouseover(function () {
     $(this.element."img.member_profile_comment_show_delete_button").show();
  });
  $("tr.member_profile_comment_row_frame").mouseout(function () {
     $(this.element."img.member_profile_comment_show_delete_button").hide();
  });
```

The thing I want is that the table row is having a element in it specified with the class **member_profile_comment_show_delete_button** should show and hide on `mouseover` and `mouseout` the table row! But there are many table rows like this! And I'm not able to find out a way display only that img in the table row over which mouse is pointed!

Please help me out!

Comment: can you show your complete page markup here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this.element in your code, just the selector; the `this` afterwards means look inside this element.

```
 $("tr.member_profile_comment_row_frame").mouseover(function () {
     $("img.member_profile_comment_show_delete_button", this).show();
 });
 $("tr.member_profile_comment_row_frame").mouseout(function () {
     $("img.member_profile_comment_show_delete_button", this).hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [`.delegate()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) here. Looks like:

```
$('table').delegate('tr', 'mouseenter', function(e) {
    $(this).find('img.member_profile_comment_show_delete_button').show();
}).delegate('tr', 'mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).find('img.member_profile_comment_show_delete_button').hide();
});
```

That has the advantage, that only *one* event handler is bound for all your `<tr>` nodes (to your `<table>` node).

Your current code should work also (beside that `this.element` needs to get replaced thru `this`), but it would bind an event handler to each `<tr>` explicitly.